# Is there a way to override a package?

Tags: go

I have import statements in my code that look like this:

```
import "github.com/A/package"
```

It turns out that - temporarily - I need to use `github.com/B/package`.

Rather than modify the source, and re-modify it later, is there a way to specify an override?

Comment: What is "temporarily"? Why not just change the paths in `GOPATH` or `vendor/`?

Comment: You could possibly move `github.com/A/package` and make a symlink to `github.com/B/package`.

Comment: @Gavin: symlinks are purposely not supported in GOPATH, you would need to rename the directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079225/golang-monkey-patching)

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive

Answer (score 1):

Since Go1.11, modules allow the use of the `replace` directive in the `go.mod` file of the project. It allows to override an expressed dependency by another module.

Online reference is https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive